# Micromax A110Q shows blank screen after waking up

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I am using Micromax A110Q. It turns on perfectly and displays
 everything fine. But whenever I turn off the screen or it sleeps
 automatically, the next time I press the power button to do something
 screen doesn't display anything, although the button icons on the
 touch-pad lit up.The device was working fine before I made the following changes.

I rooted the device and installed CWM and uninstalled some of the default apps offered by Micromax. Then after installing a few things I made a backup using CWM and then again flashed my device with v2 of the stock ROM (I was learning the basics of flashing).

I then used CWM recovery to undo the changes i.e.I restored the backup which I made just before flashing. Now when my mobile boots it sometimes display:

> Unfortunately, com.google.process.gapps have stopped working

but the problem persists even when the error doesn't occur.

How should I resolve the issue? And let me know  if you need other  details.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Am I understanding correctly: you tried to restore that backup after flashing the stock ROM? Why that? If you really flashed the (unmodified) stock ROM, all the stuff should have been there again. One more thing: is the ROM you flashed identical with the one you had when performing that backup – or are those different versions?

Comment: I used version 2 to flash the device. Version 1 was on my handset before and used the same to backup and restore later.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood the logic behind it but I followed the following steps out of instincts and now the cell phone is working fine.

> 1. Reflash the android with v2
> 2. Boot in recovery mode.
> 3. Go to recovery and backup
> 4. select advance restore from sd card
> 5. Select all images except boot
> 6. Start restore
> 7. After restoring reboot

The system works fine after this.

If anyone can explain the logic behind this kindly reply.