# Display wouldn't turn on without a restart (Galaxy Note 10.1 2014)

Tags: screen, bugs, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

The device is working great until it gets locked (by single power button click). So when I lock it, it just wouldn't turn on, the buttons are working though and it seems it's still running it just showing a black screen.

Interestingly if I try to change brightness it wouldn't respond. Looks like these two related issues.

So to turn on I am having to restart the device and make sure it is *awake*

P.S: Device is not rooted

**UPDATE**
So factory reset didn't help (erase all data).

Comment: Related: [Micromax A110Q shows blank screen after waking up](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115378)

Comment: So in my case the device isn't rooted. Perhaps I have to hard reset it then

Comment: And I wouldn't mark this Question as duplicate as devices are different and one of them rooted while mine is not

Comment: That's why I wrote *related* and not *possible duplicate*.

Comment: Could you repair your device, the exact thing is happen to my tablet and i know waht to do, i've just made a hard reset, and the same thing. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zrNNczfLZ0 try this note; the connetor have 2 sides